# JavaFX Multi Threading

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I'm writing a small programm where JavaFx acts as a viewer and controler and let Java do the other hard work. I can start multiple threads from Javafx however, I'm not able to stop them. If I try to use .stop(), the threads are still running.

Here is one of them:

```
public var sleepTask_connect;

function LogOutAction(): Void {
    sleepTask_connect.stop();
}

function LogInAction(): Void {

   var listener = FXListener_interface_connection {
                override function callback(errorCode, errorMessage): Void {
                    //do something
                    if(errorCode != 200){
                        setIcn(errorMessage);
                        }
                }
            }
    sleepTask_connect = FXListener_connection {
                listener: listener
            };
    sleepTask_connect.start();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JavaTaskBase](http://java.sun.com/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.async/javafx.async.JavaTaskBase.html) to implement you Java thread. There is a stop method to kill the thread. Here is an [example](http://fxexperience.com/2009/11/writing-a-java-based-task/) of how you use it.

Comment: I have done it this way. As I said I can start the threads and they working fine. But calling the .stop() does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I've had better luck with the JFXtras XWorker component for threading. See http://jfxtras.googlecode.com/svn/site/javadoc/release-0.6/org.jfxtras.async/org.jfxtras.async.XWorker.html.

However in general in order for your thread to respond to cancel/stop requests, you have to check the canceled or stopped flag in your code during your "do something" section. This works if your thread is in an infinite loop for example, or if you just have a series of long running processes you can check for canceled/stopped in between them. Alternatively, if your code calls some blocking method (like sockets or a blocking queue), then most of these will throw an InterruptedException when the thread is canceled.